# Html email title spacing between the subject and the actual message python django

Tags: python, html, django

We are trying to implement the email function using python django and it shows extra spaces in the header in the mail box like the following screenshots[image]

[image]
Does anyone have ideas about this issue? It shows in Gmail and also Outlook. I already checked css and I think it doesn't cause this problem.

Update:
I attached the part of code related to the content here:

```
encrypted_text = str(encrypt(SECRET_KEY, text + ':' + confirmation_str) ,'utf-8')
message = Mail(
                                    from_email=from,
                                    to_emails=to,
                                    subject=subject,
                                    html_content=email_template.getEmailTemplate(encrypted_text)
                                 )
```

Comment: That's not extra space in the message, That is just spacing between the *subject* and the *actual message*.

Comment: Kindly post the code responsible for sending email

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks I just edited the title of this question!

Comment: @Muteshi Hi I just updated the part of codes!

Comment: Why are you converting to ```str```

Comment: @Muteshi That str is used to generate the URL in the getEmailTemplate() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extra spacing is usually caused by setting only the `html_content`. HTML often will come with white space. If you also set the `text_content`, this will be used instead for the email preview. An example from the django docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/) which includes a `text_content`:

```
subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'from@example.com', 'to@example.com'
text_content = 'This is an important message.'
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```